# Change Date Format

Tags: iphone, ios

1. How can I change the Date like that:Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:01:01 GMT
2. I want to change it to: 2013-2-19 08:01:01 I serched more but not
3. find any answer,if you know it,please tell me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:date]];
```

you will get `2013-2-19 08:01:01`

more NSDateFormatter info you can see : [this](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns)

and dateFormatter set like this : `@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"` you maybe can get `Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:01:01 GMT`

Comment: I means is change style_1(Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:01:01 GMT) to styel_2(2013-2-19 08:01:01)

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/"];
_dateDisplay.text = [df stringFromDate:myDate];
```

I know this is not the date format you wanted but it should put you on the correct track